# How to show the attributes of an object when clicking a button in Windows forms?

Tags: c#, class, windows-forms-designer

I want to show the attributes of an object when I click on a button in Windows Forms using c# and I don't know how to do it. Part of my code looks like this until now. I'm a beginner in c#.

```
class Pizza: ICloneable
    {
        private string nume;
        private int nrIngrediente;
        private string[] ingrediente;

        public Pizza()
        {
            nume = "Margherita";
            nrIngrediente = 2;
            ingrediente = new string[nrIngrediente];
            for (int i = 0; i < nrIngrediente; i++)
            {
                ingrediente[0] = "Sos rosii";
                ingrediente[1] = "Mozzarella";
            }
        }



        public Pizza(string den, int nri, string[] ing)
        {
            nume = den;
            nrIngrediente = nri;
            ingrediente = new string[nrIngrediente];
            for (int i = 0; i < nrIngrediente; i++)
                ingrediente[i] = ing[i];
        }

        public Pizza(Pizza p)
        {
            nume = p.nume;
            nrIngrediente = p.nrIngrediente;
            ingrediente = new string[nrIngrediente];
            for (int i = 0; i < nrIngrediente; i++)
                ingrediente[i] = p.ingrediente[i];
        }

        public string PizzaName
        {
            get { return nume; }
            set { nume = value; }
        }

 public int PizzaNrIng
        {
            get { return nrIngrediente; }
            set { nrIngrediente = value; }


//also, i don't know how to write the getter and setter for this one
      public string PizzaIngredients
        //{
        //    get
        //    {
        //        for(int i=0;i<nrIngrediente;i++) 
        //            return ingrediente[i];
        //    }
        //    set { ingrediente = value; }
        //}
```

And now, the form code is the following(note that i designed it already):

```
 public partial class ListaPizza : Form
    {

        public ListaPizza()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Margherita_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] ingrMargh = new string[2] { "Sos rosii", "Mozzarella" };
            Pizza Margherita = new Pizza("Margherita", 2, ingrMargh);

            //Show(Margherita);
//here i want the object created above to be shown in a messagebox when i click the button in the form but i don't know how


        } 
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but you could override the `ToString` method to show exactly what you want, and then you would only need to do something like `MessageBox.Show(Marguerita.ToString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the getter and setter in below way.

```
public string PizzaIngredients
{
    get
    {
        return String.Join(",",nringrediente);
    }
    set
    {
        nringrediente = value.Split(',');
    }
}
```

And Show(Margherita); can be implemented like in Pizza Class :

```
public string GetDisplayMessageForPizza()
{
    return "My Pizza is " + nume + ". It contains " + nringrediente + " ingredients : " + PizzaIngredients;
}
```

And in form ListaPizza  :

```
private void Margherita_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] ingrMargh = new string[2] { "Sos rosii", "Mozzarella" };
    Pizza Margherita = new Pizza("Margherita", 2, ingrMargh);

    MessageBox.Show(Margherita.GetDisplayMessageForPizza());
}
```

Comment: BTW it's a bad practice to concatenate strings with "+" since strings are immutable - every addition will create a new instance of string. Better to use string.Format or StringBuilder

Comment: I know its a bad practice. I just posted answer that was expected by asker. I will be careful from next time. In GetDisplayMessageForPizza(), coder can return whatever string in required format that is to be displayed.

Comment: It works very well, but when it comes to showing me the ingredients, is says like this: It contains 2 ingredients: System.String[]. It was easier in c++ with for to read them all, haha @Vandita

Comment: oh my bad, i wrote something bad. sorry for the inconvenience and thank you so much for helping me. have a nice day!@Vandita

Comment: Good luck ! :) @Anais. If you have solved your issue using my code please mark this as answer.

Comment: Hey. Sorry for bothering again, but if i had an int, not a string, how could i write the getter and setter? example:  private int nrIngrediente;
        private int[] weight; @Vandita

Comment: @Anais in the same way. `String.Join` for getter and for setter for int[], `nringrediente = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(value.Split(','), int.Parse);`. If your variable is List<int> then `nringrediente = value.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox.Show();

has to be a string value so any parts of your object that is not a string will need the .ToString() method

Or if you want to customize the view you could pass the object to a new form and create a whole nice layout for it with the designer.

Answer (score 0):

As for the getter - you should return an array of strings, not just a string:

```
public string[] PizzaIngredients
{
    get
    {
        ingrediente;
    }
    set 
    { 
        ingrediente = value; 
    }
}
```

As for the showing - just use MessageBox.Show():

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} {1}", Margherita.Name, Margherita.nrIngrediente));
```